# kendo MVVM data-bind dropdownlist

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

How can I bind a local array to the MVVM dropdownlist of kendo.

I have an array like this

```
var array = [0.0, 20.00]
```

and I want to bind it to my input control

```
<input data-role="dropdownlist"
       data-bind='"source: ' + array + '"' />
```

Its not working. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your question whether you have forgotten to use [`kendo.bind()` to bind the View to the ViewModel](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/overview) but I suggest you also review the [Kendo UI Framework Source Binding documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/source) for the syntax of data-bind. Also check the [DropDownList MVVM Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/mvvm) for a more complete example. A minimalist implementation is shown below:

```
<body id="appRoot">
  <p>Minimalist DropDownList example</p>
  <input data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="source: array">
  <script>
    // Ideally you would use this viewModel variable instead of the plain JavaScript object literal below
    var viewModel = kendo.observable( { array: [ 0.0, 20.00 ] } );

    kendo.bind($("#appRoot"), { array: [ 0.0, 20.00 ] } );
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The MVVM source binding accepts **model field**, and not a variable in the window scope. If you would like just bind the DropDownList to primitive values, then use the **data-source** attribute:

```
<input data-role="dropdownlist" data-source="array" />
```

Here is a runnable [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ggkrustev/IruX).

If you would like to use the source binding, then define a view model. Here is another [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ggkrustev/IruX/2) that demonstrates this approach.